# configure cuckoo guest machine for dynamic malware analysis

Tags: malware

I've configured Cuckoo on my host machine, now trying to setup the guest machine where the malware suppose to be executed. The guest machine will be Ubuntu not Windows, but I don't know what should be done on the Ubuntu machine to mkae it Cuckoo guest machine. Where the guidance of Cuckoo shows the steps for configuring Windows 7 machine as guest machine, but nothing mentioned about Ubuntu, though Cuckoo supports linux malware analysis.

Comment: same problem here ... I have been playing with their source code a little bit ... seems like the guest.py and agaent.py contain some stuff that is specific to windows :| and I can not find any thing and i mean any thing on the net like a guide to do it :(

Comment: I contacted Cuckoo developers and they mentioned they are still working on improving the analysis of Linux-based malware

Comment: you might want to see here  [link](https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues/1546) errorPage
I did start playing with the code my self but seems people have done some stuff already. there seems to be a lot of windows spesific and architecture specific code in there .hopefully in the coming version we'll see some thing and there is a link to somebody's setup online which you can use for free. should that fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, and here there my conversation with them 
https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues/1455

Might be you can find some useful information.